# Facebook feed flow : How to show popup on user action?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to submit some content via facebook php sdk, and while on my computer (localhost then) using my test app, everything goes fine.
But on my web server (PROD), $userId keeps returning 0 while I'm logged in :

```
// PROD
define('YOUR_APP_ID', 'XXXXXX');
define('SECRET_KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');

//TEST
//define('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YYYYYYY');
//define('SECRET_KEY', 'YYYYYYYYYYYY');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
        'secret' => SECRET_KEY,
));


$userId = $facebook->getUser();
```

(and I'm sure that the app id and secret are ok)

Any idea why ?

Comment: while I can get the userId before the php call with javascript, should I send the userId via POST ?

Comment: I found the solution : I just had to add `cookie  : true` in the FB.init() function...